# Differentiate between snapshots and official releases, while deploying exactly what has been tested

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, versioning, release-management

Suppose the following situation:

1. A CI server generated regular snapshot artifacts
2. At some point, an artifact is considered "stable" and is given to QA for testing

   1. If it passes, it's deployed as an official release
   2. If it doesn't pass, a newer snapshot gets tested until one passes

Given an arbitrary build, we want to be able to verify whether this build is an official release or not.

Suppose also that the customer's machines are not connected to the internet, so there's no way to query a database with release information or check a license server.

Now, one rule is to *release exactly what has been tested*, which rules out binary patching of the artifacts or recompilation to a "release" flavour.

Is there a workflow which meets all these constraints?

Comment: can you spell out what you are doing? you edit the binary snapshot? you give out v1.x before it passes testing, so you have bad versions in the wild?

Comment: @Ewan I think the problem is equivalent to: “I'm testing a release candidate `v1.0-RC4`. Once that passes QA, I want to release that exact artefact as `v1.0`, but the compiled-in version string says it's a release candidate, not the final release. And I can't designate one artefact as a release before it passes through the QA process, because it would never actually be released should it fail QA.” – there's no obvious path around this deadlock except for relabelling a successful RC as a release and sending it through QA again, knowing that it will work, but that's just unnecessary work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cryptographically sign a release, but not a release candidate/snapshot.

The code could check if its own package has a valid signature, if the signature on the package is missing or invalid, then show the rc number, otherwise if the signature is valid the rc number is not shown.

Comment: I like that solution. Since we want our non-release snapshots to be signed as well, we will are going to modify it a bit: Use a different certificate for releases, and show the rc number if it's a "non-release" snapshot.

Comment: hate to nitpick, but this is effectively just adding an extra file to the snapshot. sure its not a code file, but your test is "release exactly what has been tested"

Answer (score 3):

This is the 'standard' workflow in my experience.

- feature branch new features
- when 'dev complete' merge to develop
- ci builds on develop and assigns incremental version number (no -RC)
- build auto deployed to qa (artifact goes to octopus)
- testers test
- fixes merged into dev
- test pass
- merge to master
- deploy passed version promoted to live
- rollback (joke)

So no. Given just a random artifact outside of the workflow you cant tell if its passed testing or not.

What protects your users from running RC code is the deployment process itself.

Now, if you are developing desktop software, you cant just force your users to upgrade. So if you are handing out Beta software you are right, you have to either rebuild, or reversion the final RC build to get nice non-beta version numbers etc.

But lets say you decide to rebuild. Now you might introduce bugs because, its not the same binary right?

But! You are going to test that binary anyway right? so what you really have is TWO release workflows. One for betas and one for Production releases. A beta build is never a production build and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

> Given an arbitrary build, we want to be able to verify whether this
>   build is a snapshot or an official release.

Well, from your description **all** the builds are snapshots (created in step 1) but **only some** of them are officially released (in step 2.1), so I guess you just want to know if it's an official release or not :)

One possible approach would be policy-based:

- In a customer environment, even if you don't have access to a release DB the answer **should always** be an official release (unreleasable code should never make it to the customer; maybe even nuke it or just restrict access to it in step 2.2 to prevent accidental deployment).
- In your own environment you *should* be able to lookup the snapshot version ID into the release database and get your answer.

Comment: > Well, from your description all the builds are snapshots (created in step 1) but only some of them are officially released (in step 2.1), so I guess you just want to know if it's an official release or not :)
You're right, I have changed the original question.